# What does "apt" stand for?

Tags: apt

What does the abbreviation "apt" stand for?  I'm referring to the "apt" directory, the "apt-cache", and the "apt-get" package manager.

I always assumed "apt-get" was short for "get application", but i'm probably wrong.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From `man apt`

```
apt(8)                                                                                                                                                                  apt(8)

NAME
       apt - Advanced Package Tool
```

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool